# Android App actions issues when English Articles are used as a part of speech

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

We have implemented android shortcuts. Testing of App actions on physical devices was fine, except for an issue with English Articles.

When English Articles appear as a part of a statement, the statement is not recognized as an action, and Assistant does not redirected to the app. For example, 'add note to Express Scheduler' is recognized, while 'add a note to Express Scheduler' is not.
My question is whether anybody have experienced similar issues?
Please, see capabilities segment extracted from shortcuts.xml. I am  using actions.intent.CREATE_THING and actions.intent.GET_THING BIIs. I've listed one example above: '***add note to Express Scheduler***' is recognized, while '***add a note to Express Scheduler***' is not.

```
<capability android:name="actions.intent.CREATE_THING">
    <intent>
        <url-template android:value="https://vijac.ca/schedule{?name,description}" />
        <parameter
            android:name="thing.name"
            android:key="name"
            android:required="false" />
        <parameter
            android:name="thing.description"
            android:key="description"
            android:required="false" />
    </intent>
</capability>

<capability android:name="actions.intent.GET_THING">
    <intent>
        <url-template android:value="https://vijac.ca/search{?name}" />
        <parameter
            android:name="thing.name"
            android:key="name" />
    </intent>
</capability>enter code here
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you update your question to include the exact BII that you're trying to use and an example `<capability>` block that you're using to test? The more information you can provide, the better our chances are of being able to test the issue.

Comment: Thank you, yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think what may be happening is that you have a very generic name of the thing ("a note"), when it is expecting to handle specific names which normally don't need an article ("Pixel 4", "Stairway to Heaven").

You may want to try one of these to address the problem:

- The `thing.name` parameter for that BII [allows](https://developer.android.com/reference/app-actions/built-in-intents/common/create-thing#use-inline-inventory) for an [inline inventory](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/inline-inventory) which is a way of setting allowable values and alises for those values. You can create an inventory item for note that has aliases such as "a note" and "note".
- Consider using the [`actions.intent.CREATE_DIGITAL_DOCUMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/app-actions/built-in-intents/productivity/create-digital-document) BII which indicates that it supports phrases such as "Create a note".